# How to interpret the smoother matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, spline

For example, in the smoothing spline problem, finally we get:
$$\hat{y}=S_\lambda y$$
where $S_\lambda$ is the (linear) smoother matrix. But how to interpret it?

Furthermore, ESL has a discussion about the $S_\lambda$. If we do the eigendecomposition of it, we get
$$S_\lambda=\sum_{i=1}^N\rho_k(\lambda)u_ku_k^T$$ then
$$\hat{y}=S_\lambda y=\sum_{i=1}^Nu_k\rho_k(\lambda)\langle u_k,y\rangle$$
It says that "the smoothing spline operates by decomposing y w.r.t the complete basis ${u_k}$, and differentially shrinking the contributions using $\rho_k(\lambda)$". What does that mean?

Comment: I think they mean that each component in the eigensystem will shrink corresponding "part" of the vector differently much depending on the eigenvalue magnitude. It's just really horribly worded.

Comment: @mathreadler, thank you, sorry for the statement but my emphasis is what "decomposing y w.r.t the complete basis $u_k$" means?

Comment: It means to write it as a linear combination of the vectors spanning that basis $u_k$. To find the scalar weights in that linear combination.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to brush up the language of linear algebra.

A **complete basis** for $R^2$ is any basis in which any vector in the space can be written as linear combination of the basis vectors.

It can be spanned by for example the vectors $[1,0]^T$ and $[1,3]^T$

In this basis, the vector $[0,3]^T$ can be written as $-1\cdot [1,0]^T +1\cdot[1,3]^T$ because if you multiply in the scalars and add up element-wise it will equal 0 and 3 in those positions.

If the vectors above were eigenvectors to the smoothing operator then what it would do if applied (multiplied) would be to separately multiply the scalars -1 and +1 above with two different values : the **eigenvalues** of the operator. And the vector belonging to each eigenvalue would be called an **eigenvector**.

All of this you can read in a first linear algebra book if you have one.

Comment: So if $S_\lambda=UDU^T$, $U$ is the matrix constructed by the eigenvectors, then why $S_\lambda y =UDU^T y$ is "decomposing y"? It is not like projection, right?

Comment: It is a decomposition in the sense that we consider the vector a linear combination of the basis vectors in the basis

Comment: To be specific, are we considering $y$ a linear combination of $U$? But it seems not to make sense

Comment: The vectors of the basis are stored in the transform matrix.

Comment: You say transform matrix, do you mean $S_\lambda$?

Comment: A transform matrix moves us from one basis to another.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get your point. Can you use the example in smoothing spline to express it ? like in notation of "$S_\lambda~U~y$"

Comment: No I can't. I also have job to do. Maybe you can read some more in book.